# How to automatically crop to a rectangle after creating panorama from unaligned images?

Tags: photoshop, panorama, automation, cropping

I used Photoshop CS6 "Photomerge" feature to stitch together 5 images I took with my Nexus 4. 
The images are not horizontally aligned, thus resulting in a panorama with "jagged edges"
The question is how do I crop the biggest possible rectangle from the panorama without getting into the transparent (empty) space?

Yes, I know I can do it manually with the crop tool but is there a faster, easier, more convenient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a dedicated stitching package, like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net), before editing in Photoshop.  Hugin has [an autocrop function](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Crop_tab).

Comment: Thanks a lot
After doing so much searching, I found that Photoshop has no such feature.
The program you recommended does exactly the job I wanted.
Since it's open-source, maybe we can turn it into a Photoshop plug-in :D

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an action to select areas that have no image and do a context aware fill.  This way you won't need to crop if there is enough information at the edges of your frame and the results are usually great when it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any sort of automatic crop functionality as part of Photoshop CS6's photomerge feature.

Another option to consider is that in many cases, content aware fill can do a great job of filling in the vacant areas near the jagged edges, giving you a larger resulting file.